# python trivia game error

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, debugging

Trying to have a game where each question has a unique value associated to it. The player's score is then the total number of points of the questions she or he answers correctly. Been fiddling with it but I keep running into these errors :
[image]

code:

```
# Trivia Challenge
# Trivia game that reads a plain text file

import sys

def open_file(file_name, mode):
    """Open a file."""
    try:
        the_file = open(file_name, mode)
    except IOError as e:
        print("Unable to open the file", file_name, "Ending program.\n", e)
        input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        return the_file

def next_line(the_file):
    """Return next line from the trivia file, formatted."""
    line = the_file.readline()
    line = line.replace("/", "\n")
    return line

def next_block(the_file):
    """Return the next block of data from the trivia file."""
    category = next_line(the_file)
    point_value = 0
    question = next_line(the_file)

    answers = []
    answers.append(next_line(the_file))

    if( answers[0]=="True\n"):
        answers.append(next_line(the_file))
    else:
        for i in range(4):
            answers.append(next_line(the_file))

    correct = next_line(the_file)
    if correct:
        correct = correct[0]
        point_value = (int)(next_line(the_file).strip())
    explanation = next_line(the_file) 

    return category, question, answers, correct, explanation, point_value

def welcome(title):
    """Welcome the player and get his/her name."""
    print("\t\tWelcome to Trivia Challenge!\n")
    print("\t\t", title, "\n")

def main():
    trivia_file = open_file("trivia.txt", "r")
    title = next_line(trivia_file)
    welcome(title)
    score = 0

    # get first block
    category, question, answers, correct, explanation, point_value = next_block(trivia_file)
    while category:
        # ask a question
        print(category)
        print(question)
        i=0
        for a in answers:
            print ("\t", i + 1, "-", a)
            i = i + 1        # get answer

        answer = input("What's your answer?: ")

        # check answer
        if answer == correct:
            print("\nRight!", end=" ")
            score += 1
        else:
            print("\nWrong.", end=" ")
        print(explanation)
        print("Score:", score, "\n\n")

        # get next block
        category, question, answers, correct, explanation, score, point_value = next_block(trivia_file)

    trivia_file.close()

    print("That was the last question!")
    print("You're final score is", score)

main() 
input("\n\nPress the enter key to exit.")
```

not sure why it's having these errors/why its not running - suggestions? ty!

this is connected to a seperate .txt file named "trivia.txt" with all the questions and points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the error is occurring because your text file contains unicode characters. You can add the `encoding` parameter to the `open` call to tell python that it isn't in the default `ascii` encoding.

```
the_file = open(file_name, mode, encoding='utf-8')
```

If this doesn't work, it may be because the file is using a different encoding such as 'iso-8859-15'.

The Python documentation [Unicode-HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html) has more details about dealing with [Reading and Writing Unicode Data](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#reading-and-writing-unicode-data).